# Thunderbird filtering drafts?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I recently face the problem that I answer an e-mail which is filtered, my answer gets saved into the draft folder on the IMAP server and then for some reason a message filter catches it and moves it to the same folder where the message that I am answering resides.

Is there a way to prevent Thunderbird to run message filters on the drafts folder?

(I am using Thunderbird 24.3.0)

Comment: This is an old bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681474 We are still waiting for a fix for it. You could try using POP3 or maybe using different filters (are you maybe using a filter with "from, to, cc, bcc"?)

Comment: So old that I already forgot what workaround did I use. :) (POP3 wasn't an option so I most likely went with the different filters case...)

Comment: You should post your workaround, to not leave the question all alone in the space :)

Comment: But not using the filter because it caused problems isn't really an answer. It's like answering "you shouldn't use Thunderbird, because it's buggy"

Comment: Ahahahah true. Well..it seems we will have to wait until they resolve the issue. At least people passing by will know the bug it's still there in 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of October 2016, the problem seems to be fixed.

**Hurrican39** writes:

```
Just made a try with version 45.4.0 and it seems to be fixed.
Filter is not applied when Autosave is called.
There's only one copy of the saved document in the Drafts folder after multiple autosave.
```

**Geoffroy Ménard** writes:

```
I'm using TB50 and this thing just happened to me.
I worked around it by adding a "sender is not me" condition to my filter.
I have quickFilters module installed.
```

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681474